# Asp classic is supported on Crystal Report 2016?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, asp-classic, visual-foxpro

know im using vfp and foxweb and i use the reports from vfp but sometimes we get errors with the print of server so we want to change to crystal reports. 
I started to resarch and saw something that i don´t understand, does crystal report 2016 supports asp classic? or i need to upgrade to asp.net?

Comment: What kind of problems are you getting with VFP reports?

Comment: When let's say that four or five people send to print a vfp report, with convert it in pdf and show them the pdf, the problem is that sometimes the print start to fail and we can´t print anymore pdf till we restart the foxweb, so we're looking for an alternative to print pdf

Comment: Have you looked at FoxyPreviewer? http://www.foxypreviewer.com/

Comment: I saw it but I`m afraid that i happen the same cuz' it's also a .prg file, idk what's the difference between them

Comment: FoxyPreviewer is written in VFP. It's not a separate product.